# Woocommerce - sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a Solution to fix this Error. CMS Wordpress(4.4.21), plugin Woocommerce(2.1.6). PHP(7.3.6)

sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
/var/www/u0900579/data/www/xxx/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-conditional-functions.php
on line 237

```
function is_filtered() {
        global $_chosen_attributes;

        ERROR! ------>  return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_is_filtered', ( sizeof( $_chosen_attributes ) > 0 || ( isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) && isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is given to you in the error message. The parameter you hand to `count()`, which in this case is the variable `$_chosen_attributes `, **must** be an array or an object that implements `Countable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the content of $_chosen_attributes?
Try to typecast the variable:

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_is_filtered', ( sizeof( (array) $_chosen_attributes ) > 0 || ( isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) && isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) ) );
```